# WiX Binder Variables in bundle's Variable element

Tags: wpf, wix

I'm using three projects:

- A simple MSI package written in WiX;
- Managed Bootstrapper Application (custom .NET user interface) in WPF;
- and a WiX bootstrapper to combine them, along with installing .NET framework.

The simple MSI is of course the main project, and the rest are only GUI and framework dependencies. Still, the release project is actually the bootstrapper one. Thus, I wanted to bind the simple MSI package version with the bundle's one, and had done it successfully with WiX [binder variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/light.html).

As a next step, I want to display the bundle version somehow in the WPF UI project, and had tried to pass it with Burn's [Variable element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/variable.html):

```
<Variable Name="BundleVersion" Value="!(bind.packageVersion.MyPackageId)" Type="string" Persisted="true" />
```

Unfortunately and strangely, the binder variable does not being processed, and the BundleVersion holds the raw, plain string that appears in the attribute. Why does it happened, and how to solve it?

Note that *BootstrapperApplicationData.xml* does not include any information about versions (WiX Toolset 3.8), so it's irrelevant to this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [a bug](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/3914/) that was fixed in WiX 3.9.  The WiX 3.9 RC was released last week.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! By the way, is there a good reason for the absence of version information in the BootstrapperApplicationData.xml?

Comment: There's already a built-in variable for the bundle version: [WixBundleVersion](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html).  The version for the packages in the xml file was also added in WiX 3.9.